# AMD OpenCL does not detect Intel HD 4000 as a GPU device

Tags: ubuntu, gpu, intel

I have a laptop which comes with Intel HD 4000 graphics. I am running Ubuntu 12.04. Now, when I ran some opencl examples that come with the AMD OpenCL SDK, the SDK used the CPU, because no GPU device could be recognized.

The System Details screen shows **"Graphics   Intel® Ivybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2"**. Running lspci shows:

```
$lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 vga 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor
Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
  Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:2208]
  Kernel driver in use: i915
  Kernel modules: i915
```

I believe that this confirms that Intel HD 4000 is working on my machine. But I am not sure why it is not being recognized by the opencl examples as a GPU device. Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The title of your question says it: you need to install Intel OpenCL SDK in order to run on an Intel GPU, since AMD OpenCL is targeted towards AMD GPUs. Download Intel OCL SDK [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl-sdk) and make sure that your driver supports OpenCL.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem.
Installed Intel's SDK (`opencl_runtime_14.2_x64_4.5.0.8`).
And it sees only the processor, no graphics card.
(And it is actually strange -- I think I did run OpenCL on this same laptop's graphics couple years ago. Maybe an old version of SDK would catch the card.)

[People say](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/dev/forum_thread.php?id=8759):
"Intel doesn't supply OpenCL support for their GPUs under Linux."

[And add](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412009/open-cl-in-intel): "go for `beignet`."
Apparently, `beignet` is an open source project spawned by Intel for developing open driver by the community for Linux.